# What do "<, >" mean as syntax in this context?-- std::auto_ptr< sql::Statement > stmt(con->createStatement());

Tags: c++

```
std::auto_ptr< sql::Statement > stmt(con->createStatement());
```

I looked through my textbook but there is no mention of anything of this sort.  Can someone tell me what it is called so I  can look it up?  The only use of "<" I know is as a binary less-then operator.

Comment: Please, for the love of puppies and all that is good in this world, read a book! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a template. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28programming%29

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked a very basic question, I would like to point you to the c++ faq, where this and lots of other (simple and complex questions are already answered) :
[c++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/)

The answer to your specific question among [template questions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html)